# spaghetti plots for binned longitudinal data with timepoints

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data frame containing longitudinal data that looks like this

> test

```
    Names     hr1    hr2    hr3    hr4      workhr_bin
      41     80     76     70     60               7
      42     80     74     75     NA               8
      43     85     NA     60     65               6
      44     NA     NA     NA     60               3
      45     80     70     NA     NA               8
      46     NA     NA     NA     60               3
```

Variables for `hr1`, `hr2`, `hr3`, `hr4` include reported hours of service at repeated timed intervals for the subjects under the "Name" column. The "workhr_bin" column includes bins obtained from using the quantile function. There are ten bins total, 1:10.

I am trying to generate multiple spaghetti plots of hours faceted by bins. Essentially it should yield 10 plots, one plot for data in bin 1, another plot for data bin 2 etc.

I tried doing :

```
head(melt(test[,c(2:6)]))
```

But I end up with the `workhr_bin` variable gone and a file like this instead:

```
  variable value
1   hours1    80
2   hours1    80
3   hours1    85
4   hours1    NA
5   hours1    80
6   hours1    NA
```

I've also tried

```
melt(test, id.var = "Names")
```

and I end up with the `workhr_bin` variable also gone

```
   Names variable value
    41   hr1      80.00
    42   hr1      80.00
    43   hr1      85.00
```

I tried using `lattice` and `ggplot2` but for some reason I cannot get my data into the right format to generate spaghetti 10 plots representative of samples within each bin.

Essentially I need a data frame with:

```
Names    variable     value    workhr_bin
    41   hr1      80.00             7
    42   hr1      80.00             8
    43   hr1      85.00             6
```

Then I would like to be able to create a bin-faceted multicolored spaghetti plots with "variable" on the x.axis (consisting of `hr1`, `hr2`, `hr3`, `hr4`) and the corresponding "value" on the y-axis. [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should study the documentation of `reshape2::melt`.

```
DF <- read.table(text="    Names     hr1    hr2    hr3    hr4      workhr_bin
      41     80     76     70     60               7
      42     80     74     75     NA               8
      43     85     NA     60     65               6
      44     NA     NA     NA     60               3
      45     80     70     NA     NA               8
      46     NA     NA     NA     60               3", header=TRUE)

library(reshape2)
DF_melt <- melt(DF, id.vars=c("Names", "workhr_bin"))
#make time numeric
DF_melt$variable <- as.numeric(gsub("hr", "", DF_melt$variable))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(DF_melt, aes(x=variable, y=value, color=factor(Names))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(workhr_bin ~ .)

print(p)
```

(This results in warnings from ggplot2 since there is not enough data. I assume your real dataset won't have this problem.)